# Can i make variables work within If statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

How can i make this variable work withing the if statement in python?

```
arrived = input('Have the doorbell ringed?: ')

if arrived == 'yes' or 'Yes':
    doorbell = input('Is it from ifood?: ')
elif arrived == 'no' or 'No':
    print('It is not here yet, keep waiting')
else:
    print('Please answer the first question with yes or no')

if doorbell == 'yes' or 'Yes':
    print('Your ifood have arrived!!!')
elif doorbell == 'no' or 'No':
    print('It is not your ifood yet, keep waiting')
else:
    print('Please answer the questions with yes or no')
```

I'm a beginner and this started as an exercice, i've been searching this for a while and i know variables are global in python but is there a way to make it work?

Comment: set `doorbell = None` at the beginning of script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your if statement is wrong - it needs to include a second `arrived ==` or it won't work. It should look like this.

```
if arrived == 'yes' or arrived == 'Yes':
```

Second, you probably want to chuck the second if-elif-else inside the first if statement, since it should only trigger if that if statement condition is fulfilled.

Full solution:

```
arrived = input('Have the doorbell ringed?: ')

if arrived == 'yes' or arrived == 'Yes':
    doorbell = input('Is it from ifood?: ')
    if doorbell == 'yes' or 'Yes':
        print('Your ifood have arrived!!!')
    elif doorbell == 'no' or 'No':
        print('It is not your ifood yet, keep waiting')
    else:
        print('Please answer the questions with yes or no')
elif arrived == 'no' or arrived == 'No':
    print('It is not here yet, keep waiting')
else:
    print('Please answer the first question with yes or no')
```

Comment: Or do `arrived = input('Have the doorbell ringed?: ').lower()` and just ask for `if arrived == 'yes':`. Now you can input "Yes" or "yes" or "YES" or "yeS" ...

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` is wrong. Better is:

```
  if arrived == 'yes' or arrived == 'Yes':
```

or

```
  if arrived in ['yes','Yes']:
```

Comment: the second one asked for a white space after the comma, but it worked for the ifs, thank you!

Comment: *the second one asked for a white space after the comma*  Can't reproduce.